# Visual Studio 2022 keeps asking for Git credentials even though it says authorization was successful

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I am trying to get Visual Studio set up on my computer and I want to use Git through Visual Studio. I have Visual Studio working with Git fine on my laptop for whatever reason, on my desktop it just doesn't work.

I am never getting past this point:

[what im seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWZHG.png)

[sign-in options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94UY4.png)

I changed the option for "Add and authenticate accounts using:" to system web browser from embedded web browser. I really dont know what else to check or what to fix. On my laptop all I had to do was click the re-enter credentials and it would log me in.

It is especially confusing because when I click re-enter credentials. Github opens and I am able to confirm my account with 2FA and then it says: "Your authorization was successful. You can now return to Visual Studio". But when I return... it still says "re-enter credentials". This is becoming very frustrating and Im considering not using Visual Studio and returning to VSCode. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your pictures look like nothing I've ever seen. You probably need to provide more context. Exactly what are you installing on your machine? What kind of authentication are you using (or think you are using) for Github? How are you using Git with Visual Studio? It looks like you have something going on here with Azure, not Visual Studio or Github (or Git). Are you doing something here in Visual Studio options?

Comment: In short, typically - you install Visual Studio, clone a repository (however you like to do it), and then start working. You shouldn't really have to mess about with anything at all. Though I do prefer (my opinion) to set up SSH authentication to github.

Comment: Where is this "Add and authenticate accounts using:" ?

Comment: @topsail I used to use SSH when I would work in VSCode. But I've found that I really like using VS for my graphics programming projects. Im not sure really what kind of authentication this is trying to use it doesnt give me tons of info. I know I can just clone it down in my terminal and work on it in visual studio, but I was hoping I could integrate my git workflow into my IDE so that I can commit and push from the IDE itself. I wish it gave me more info as to what is happening but thats really all it is. It looks like I entered my credentials successfully but I cant access my repos in vs.

Comment: @topsail That is in the tools > options > environment > accounts. I saw that on a forum somewhere that that fixed it for someone else but it didnt fix my case sadly.

Comment: If you don't know what kind of authentication you are using, I'd recommend you start using ssh as that is the easiest (I think, anyway). See: [connecting-to-github-with-ssh](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) (you can also just go straight to [checking-for-existing-ssh-keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys) and start the steps right there.

Comment: tools | options | accounts - I don't think this is relevant to your situation at all. Well, actually, no idea what its for. Generally speaking, you should be able to use github ssh authentication in Visual Studio the same as you do in VSCode, and then perform github actions from the Git menu options in VS.

Comment: @topsail WOW. All I had to do was remove my Github account and then re-add it and it seems to work fine now. I tried that previously and it didn't work. My apologies. Thanks for taking a look at this with me though.

Comment: Ah okay good deal.

Answer (score 5):

If you ever get this very odd case of Visual Studio being stuck on "Re-enter Credentials" for Git, you can try removing the account by clicking your profile image in the top right by the 'minimize' button, clicking the 3 dots by your GitHub account, and then clicking "Remove account." Then, re-add your account.

That's what worked for me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting 'The connection was reset' page until I went to
**Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Accounts**
and chose '**System web browser**' instead of 'Embedded web browser'

P.S. it worked only after I made Edge my default web browser